# Removing empty XML elements after creating new elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm aware there's a lot of examples online of how to remove empty XML elements with XSLT, however I can't find a way that will work with my document. I've created templates that write new elements and would like to process a final template that matches all elements that have no text content inside, this includes elements that are children. If an element contains a child that has no text, I would like only the empty child to be removed. I've tried using identify transforms but they don't seem to work with they way I've setup my templates, but I'd like to keep this structure.

**XML**

```
<fruitSet>
    <fruit>
        <name>apple</name>
        <colour>green</colour>
        <ratings>
            <taste>10</taste>
            <look>8</look>
        </ratings>
    </fruit>
    <fruit>
        <name>strawberry</name>
        <colour>red</colour>
        <ratings>
            <taste>7</taste>
            <look>5</look>
        </ratings>
    </fruit>    
        <fruit>
        <name>Orange</name>
        <colour></colour>
        <ratings>
            <taste>3</taste>
            <look></look>
        </ratings>
    </fruit>
</fruitSet>
```

**XSL**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xsd ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">                
    <RDF>
        <xsl:apply-templates select = "fruitSet/fruit"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select = "fruitSet/fruit/ratings"/>

    </RDF>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match = "fruit">
    <Description>
        <xsl:attribute name = "ID">
            <xsl:value-of select = "name/text()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <hasColour><xsl:value-of select = "colour/text()"/></hasColour>
        <hasTasteRating>
            <xsl:apply-templates select = "ratings"/>
        </hasTasteRating>
    </Description>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match = "ratings">
    <xsl:value-of select = "taste/text()"/>
</xsl:template>




</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Desired Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<RDF xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
  <Description ID="apple">
    <hasColour>green</hasColour>
    <hasTasteRating>10</hasTasteRating>
  </Description>
  <Description ID="strawberry">
    <hasColour>red</hasColour>
    <hasTasteRating>7</hasTasteRating>
  </Description>
  <Description ID="Orange">
    <hasTasteRating>3</hasTasteRating>
  </Description>1073</RDF>
</RDF>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following XSLT-1.0 stylesheet. It implements two approaches for solving you problem:

1. Applying an `xsl:if` to skip elements you don't want in the output.
2. Restricting a general element template with a predicate

This is the whole stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xsd ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">                
        <RDF>
            <xsl:apply-templates select = "fruitSet/fruit"/>
        </RDF>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match = "fruit">
        <Description>
            <xsl:attribute name = "ID">
                <xsl:value-of select = "name/text()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:if test="normalize-space(colour)">
                <hasColour>
                    <xsl:value-of select = "colour"/>
                </hasColour>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ratings" />
        </Description>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Only create a <hasTasteRating> element for all elements with a present <taste>  child -->
    <xsl:template match="*[normalize-space(taste)]" >
        <hasTasteRating>
            <xsl:value-of select="taste/text()"/>
        </hasTasteRating>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RDF xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
    <Description ID="apple">
        <hasColour>green</hasColour>
        <hasTasteRating>10</hasTasteRating>
    </Description>
    <Description ID="strawberry">
        <hasColour>red</hasColour>
        <hasTasteRating>7</hasTasteRating>
    </Description>
    <Description ID="Orange">
        <hasTasteRating>3</hasTasteRating>
    </Description>
</RDF>
```

Comment: This works great, but do you know if there is a more generic way that can remove the whole output using one template? For example if there were a lot more child element or another set, for example meatSet with meat elements, and more.

Comment: I improved my solution. It's more generic by now. But still, it is hard to create a truely general solution if the result element name differs from the matched element name. This can only be done with a general pattern or a key mapping between element names and result element names..

Comment: Yeah that's better now, although now I think of it, it's probably easier to just create another stylesheet to process the output